KKT conditions with two constraints
I am not sure if the conditions for KKT are right, or if I am missing any. I would greatly appreciate any advice, thank you.
I need to minimize $v_x^2 + v_y^2 + gh$ subject to

$(H-h)v_x^2 + 0.5gL^2-Lv_xv_y=0$ 
$h_{min}\leq 0 \leq h_{max}$

I wrote the lagrangian of f as:
$L(v_x,v_y,h, \lambda, \mu_1,\mu_2)= v_x^2 + v_y^2+gh+\lambda((H-h)v_x^2+0.5gL^2-Lv_xv_y)+\mu_1(h_{min}-h)+\mu_2(h-h_{max})$
I got the following conditions:
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_x}=2v_x +\lambda(2v_x(H-h)-Lv_y)=0$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_y}=2v_y+\lambda(-Lv_x)=0$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial h}=g+\lambda(-v_x^2)-\mu_1+\mu_2=0$
$\lambda, \mu_1, \mu_2 \geq 0$

It is really not clear what the constraint $h_\min \le 0 \le h_\max$ has to do with anything.
